# How to change the location of the keytab file in Jasig CAS under Tomcat under Windows Server

Tags: tomcat, cas, jasig

I am implementing a CAS server on a Windows 2008R2 machine. Everything is running perfect, however only when I place my keytab file in C:. My login.conf looks like this at the moment:

```
jcifs.spnego.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required storeKey=true useKeyTab=true keyTab="file:///C:\spn-account.keytab";
};
jcifs.spnego.accept {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required storeKey=true useKeyTab=true keyTab="file:///C:\spn-account.keytab";
```

I would like to change the location of the keytab file to my Tomcat directory. I've tried the following (including moving the keytab file itselft) and they both don't work:

```
jcifs.spnego.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required storeKey=true useKeyTab=true keyTab="file:///C:\Program%20Files\spn-account.keytab";
};
jcifs.spnego.accept {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required storeKey=true useKeyTab=true keyTab="file:///C:\Program%20Files\Tomcat\spn-account.keytab";
```

and

```
jcifs.spnego.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required storeKey=true useKeyTab=true keyTab="file:///C:\Progra~1\Tomcat\spn-account.keytab";
};
jcifs.spnego.accept {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required storeKey=true useKeyTab=true keyTab="file:///C:\Progra~1\Tomcat\spn-account.keytab";
```

Does anyone have a clue how I can change the keytab file location to my Tomcat directory?

Comment: The cleanest way to define a path that has a space in the path for use in Java is to use the 8dot3 short name format. Use "dir /x" to determine the 8dot3 name of the Program Files and use that. It will look like "PROGRAM~1".

Comment: Have you tried java-ifying those paths?  Change all the "\" to "/" or "\\\\".  In fact, give both a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using java-style paths for the keyTab.  Use forward slashes instead of backslashes; if you have to use backslashes, they need to be double-double-escaped (four backslashes any time you want one), so they can be read into Properties and then have URIs created from them.